# Assigning texture to SKSpriteNode is not working

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Changing the texture of a SKSpriteNode is not working

I'm trying to learn SpriteKit and am running into something that is puzzling me. I am trying to display a sprite. I try two methods that should work, but only one is actually causing the sprite to be displayed on the screen! I would really like to actually understand why. Can anybody help?

This works:
func loadLevel() {

```
    let point: CGPoint = CGPoint(x:300,y:300)
    var block = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Block_blue")
    block.position = point
    self.addChild(block)
```

}

This does not:

func loadLevel() {

```
    let point: CGPoint = CGPoint(x:300,y:300)
    var block = SKSpriteNode()
    block.position = point
    block.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Block_blue")
    self.addChild(block)
```

}

I would expect both functions to result in displaying the sprite, but only the first works? I would like to understand what is going on here.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please [reformat your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) using the linked guide.

Comment: You're not setting the `size` property in the second function. SpriteKit uses the image size to create the sprite in the first function.

Comment: As @0x141E said before, you need to set your size in order to see the object. On the method you used, the object is indeed created, but because you didn't set the block.size with your custom values, he will use the default ones CGSize(width: 0, height: 0). If you will change the block.size = CGSize(width: custom_width, height: custom_height) you should see the object.

Comment: Great! Thank you all!